# Transfer WhatsApp chat from iPhone to Android

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, ios, chat

I recently moved from iPhone to Android, now I want to transfer all my WhatsApp chats to my new Android phone from iPhone, but the problem is WhatsApp doesn't have any feature to transfer chats between different platforms, so I was looking for third-party apps which can make this possible, but no luck till now, please share your thoughts and experiences.