# How to reimport exported WhatsApp chats? [iPhone to Android migration]

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-11, ios, miui-12.5

My friend recently made the decision to switch to Android from iOS. Since she's not particularly tech-savvy, I'm tasked with migrating her WhatsApp data from her **iPhone 7** to her new **Redmi Note 11T 5G** (MIUI 12.5.2, based on Android 11) phone.

I've tried a couple of apps that promise very straight-forward WhatsApp chat transfers between iOS and Android through a PC, but the three apps I tried were ridiculously slow, and just randomly failed mid-way after several hours of progress. However, I must note that I did find a couple of chats from 2021, which would've come only through the transfer. But surely, something was wrong if only a couple of chats, that too from 2021, were transferred over several hours.

Then I came across [this guide](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-restore-your-whatsapp-chats-iphone-android) which suggests exporting the individual chats from the iPhone, and send it by email to the new Android device. I downloaded the exported chats on the new phone before installing WhatsApp on it. I also made sure the Google Drive backups don't exist. When WhatsApp goes through the setup process however, it can't detect backups in the Google drive at the restore backups screen, and only gives me the option to skip. And when I press skip, it goes straight to the main chats page, and doesn't recognise the exported chats. Should I move these chats to a specific location? Is there a better way to move WhatsApp chats from iOS to Android?

[image: This never happened!]

The "Backup found" page shown in the image on the aforementioned guide never happened.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that the article is wrong since it never works like that (as mentioned by the 2nd commenter on that article). WhatsApp on Android can only restore from specific database format on the internal storage or WhatsApp app backup on Google Drive. Please check the linked question [Transfer WhatsApp chat from iPhone to Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195832/44325) for the solutions.

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah shucks. I did see the linked question, but since the accepted answer suggested third-party apps and also the export-import method, and the neither worked well in my situation, I thought I'll ask about it. Thanks for the help though - much appreciated. :)